How can I remove cat urine stains from hardwood flooring?
There is a cat urine stain on my spruce hardwood floor. I tried Bona hardwood cleaner and Whip-It stain cleaner, but neither removed the stain.

Also How can I remove blackened water stains from a hardwood floor?

you previously had the laminate floor tag. Was this a mistake, or do you have some kind of engineered flooring?

Hardwood and laminate are two different floors.  Laminate only looks like hardwood.  So knowing which it is, is important.
